# Subtracting one dimensional array (list of scalars) from 3 dimensional arrays using broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

I have a one dimesional array of scalar values

```
Y = np.array([1, 2])
```

I also have a 3-dimensional array:

```
X = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(2, 2, 3))
```

I am attempting to subtract each value of `Y` from `X`, so I should get back `Z` which should be of shape (2, 2, 2, 3) or maybe (2, 2, 2, 3).

I can"t seem to figure out how to do this via broadcasting.

I tried changing the change of `Y`:

```
Y = np.array([[[1, 2]]])
```

but not sure what the correct shape should be.

Comment: *which should be of shape (2,2,2,3) or maybe (2,2,2,3).* Uh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcasting lines up dimensions on the right. So you're looking to operate on a `(2, 1, 1, 1)` array and a `(2, 2, 3)` array.

The simplest way I can think of is using [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 1)
```

More generally:

```
Y = Y.reshape(-1, *([1] * X.ndim))
```

At most one of the arguments to `reshape` can be -1, indicating all the remaining size not accounted for by other dimensions.

To get `Z` of shape `(2, 2, 2, 3)`:

```
Z = X - Y.reshape(-1, *([1] * X.ndim))
```

If you were OK with having `Z` of shape `(2, 2, 3, 2)`, the operation would be much simpler:

```
Z = X[..., None] - Y
```

`None` or `np.newaxis` will insert a unit axis into the end of `X`'s shape, making it broadcast properly with the 1D `Y`.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. What exactly does the  -1 do in reshape? I tried a quick google search but I couldn"t get any good hits regarding the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure on which dimension you want your subtraction to take place, but `X - Y` will not return an error if you define Y such as `Y = numpy.array([1,2]).reshape(2, 1, 1)` or `Y = numpy.array([1,2]).reshape(1, 2, 1)`.

Comment: Well, I hope you would agree it is pretty confusing to perform a subtraction on an array, which changes the original shape of the array ? From your answer, you resize Y as a 4-D array, so that when you do X - Y, you actually subtract X from Y, which is the opposite of what is written in the OP. It is clearly confusing.

Comment: It's not too bad once you get used to it